# Pandas: How to group multiple row by different criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to group row by different condition and here is the example. Basically, what I want to try is group the `Team` name and put it into a new `Dataframe` with the `sum of goal`. I have try `groupby` but somehow cannot do what I want. How can I get the expected result? Thanks!

```
example = {'Team':['Arsenal', 'Manchester United', 'Arsenal',
               'Arsenal', 'Chelsea', 'Manchester United',
               'Manchester United', 'Chelsea', 'Chelsea', 'Chelsea',
               'Juventus','Juventus'],
                 
       'Player':['Ozil', 'Pogba', 'Lucas', 'Aubameyang',
                   'Hazard', 'Mata', 'Lukaku', 'Morata', 
                                     'Giroud', 'Kante',
                'Ronaldo','Buffon'],
                                       
       'Goals':[5, 3, 6, 4, 9, 2, 0, 5, 2, 3, 20, 0] }
group_dict = {'UK':['Arsenal', 'Manchester United', 'Chelsea'], 'Italy':['Juventus']}
```

Expected Result:

```
Country    Goals
UK          39
Italy       20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a dictionary that reverse map from `Team` to `Country` and then aggregate by `Country`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(example)

df.Goals.groupby(
  df.Team.map({v: k for k, lst in group_dict.items() for v in lst}).rename('Country')
).sum().reset_index()

#  Country  Goals
#0   Italy     20
#1      UK     39
```

Comment: Thanks! but what if I have more than one column to sum up? like Goals1, Goals_yesterday, Goals_last_month?

Comment: You can sum all columns by `df[['Goals1', 'Goals_yesterday', 'Goals_last_month']].groupby(...).sum(...)...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.select` to assign a new column as `contry` temporarily and then groupby contry and call sum

```py
df.assign(contry=np.select([df['Team'].isin(v) for v in group_dict.values()],
            list(group_dict.keys()),
            '')).groupby('contry', sort=False, as_index=False)['Goals'].sum()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
  contry  Goals
0     UK     39
1  Italy     20
```

Comment: If I have more than one column to sum up? like Goals1, Goals_yesterday, Goals_last_month? just put them in the last ['Goals']?

Comment: Yeah, you can just have them as a list @WILLIAM